# How to check what messages an iFrame is sending to parent window?

Tags: javascript, iframe, addeventlistener, postmessage

I have an iFrame on my page and an event listener attached to it, but the event listener isn't being triggered. How do I see what messages (if any) the iFrame is sending to the parent window?

My javascript:

```
<script>
    var game_id = "{{game_id}}";
    var gurl = "{{game_url}}"

    window.onload=function windowLoaded(){ // wait for the page to load
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute("id", "game_frameid");
        iframe.setAttribute("name", "game_iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("src", gurl);
        iframe.textContent += "Your browser doesn't support iframes";
        console.log("created iframe object")

        function receiveMessage(event){ // A fuction for handling messages to and from the iframe

            console.log("THIS event listener triggered");

        }

        document.getElementById("iframe_div").appendChild(iframe);
        document.getElementById("game_frameid").addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
    }
```

iFrame code:

```
  var message =  {
  messageType: "SETTING",
  options: {
    "width": 700, //Integer
    "height": 300 //Integer
    }
};
window.parent.postMessage(message, "*");
```

Comment: seems you have to get the iframe in the parentWindow,and send the message from the parentWindow,then parentWindow will get that

Answer (score 0):

Like Xianshenglu said the problem was that I was listening for events directed at the iframe element in my window, but the iframe was sending messages to its parent window. So the listener should be pointed at the window the iframe is in not the iframe itself.